# Pre-filing checkout post code with a custom value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have been using this custom function below in the previous versions of WooCommerce in order to pre-fill the City and ZIP code fields:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = 'Beverly Hills';
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['default'] = '90210';
     return $fields;
}
```

It has been working great until the new WC updates.

The city still works, but the default ZIP code field **doesn't seem to work anymore**. It doesn't automatically pre-polulate the value.

Anything changed? Is there any other workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a value for 'post-code' fields doesn't work anymore as there is an autocomplete feature. Even when disable "autocomplete", this doesn't work. So the workaround is to use **jQuery** in this case.

So your code is going to be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = 'Beverly Hills';
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['autocomplete'] = "off"; // Removing autocomplete

    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form' , 'my_custom_checkout_field_postcode' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_postcode( ) {
    ?>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $('#billing_postcode').val('90210');
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

This will set correctly your the desired value in "post-code" checkout billing field.

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary have to use java-script when you use the woocommerce callback made for the job: 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value'.

The 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form' call is made for setting the attributes of the check out fields, such as disabling the autocomplete.

The point to note is this function will be repeatedly called for each and every field within the check out form.  So you switch on the field and return the value you wish assigned to the check-out form:

Based on your above code. here ya go...

```
function populating_checkout_fields ($fields, $input) 
 {
  global $woocommerce;

  switch($input)
     {
     case 'billing_city':
        $FieldValue = 'Beverly Hills';
        return $FieldValue;
     break;
     }

return $fields;  // return the default value
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'populating_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );   


 function ModifyAutoComplete($fields)
   {
   $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['autocomplete'] = null;
   }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'ModifyAutoComplete', 10, 1 );
```